# Liferay 6.1 DLApp* API: How to get images?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am migrating code which is using `IGImageService` from liferay portal 6.0 to 6.1.

I understand from this [blog post](http://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/13743587), there's a new API called `DLAppService`, which I am advised to use.

My use case is as follows: we are using a customized verion of the blogs porlet and are using `IGImage.getLargeImageId()` etc. to display differently sized versions of images from blog posts. My question:

How do is use the new (yah, kind of) `DLAppService` to retrieve image objects like before, and have access to interface methods i am used to in LR 6.0?

I see also there is `DLFileEntry`, which extends the old `IGImage` interface (in case of `#getLargeImageId()`). But I see no way to get `DLFileEntry` out of `DLAppService`.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a minor example](http://liferay-hacks.blogspot.hu/2013/12/how-to-get-or-create-new-folder-in.html) how to user `DLAppService` with folders. You can do the same with calling `DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntry()` (also handling `NoSuchFileEntryException`), and calling `DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry()` if there was no previous version of the image.

You can access the image by this URL:

```
"/image/image_gallery?uuid=" + image.getUuid() +
    "&groupId=" + serviceContext.getScopeGroupId() +
    "&t=" + System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Hope that helps something.

Comment: And do you know how I can get the getLargeImageId from com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileEntry? which is what i get using the method you're suggesting..?

Comment: You need the Image object itself? How about `ImageLocalServiceUtil.getImage(image.getLargeImageId())`?

Comment: I dont't really see how i get any sort of Image out of `DLAppLocalServiceUtil`. Using `DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntryByUuidAndGroupId` for instance gives me `com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileEntry`. From there to `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileEntry` - what's the right way?

Comment: @jhohlfeld Have you tried `ImageLocalServiceUtil` as I suggested before?

Comment: sorry, yes now i did. it is missing the `#getImageByUuidAndGroupId()` method. I suppose this really isn't the substitute for former 6.0 `IGImageLocalServiceUtil`. Maybe it's worth raising an issue in the Liferay Blogs...

Answer (score 0):

The best way by migrating code to upversion is to read the source code of new version )) See the `liferay-portal-src-6.1...\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\blogs\view_entry_content.jsp`
and you found the solution.

Comment: Yes, true. But we don't really use the blogs facility to fetch images, rather we have our own "BlogsUtil" implementation due to historical and other reasons. I'm also not very deep into Liferay APIs and could need a 1:1 code example. Please read my question carefully, since i made some effort to describe the need very specifically. If something's unclear however, don't hesitate to ask back!